# C++ Daemon log function not writing to file (Segmentation Fault?)

Tags: c++, c, linux, sockets, logging

First and foremost thanks for taking the time to read my dilemma.

On with it;

I am quite new to c/c++ field but I have a lot of experiences with other languages. I am working on a multiclient socket server that I will use for various things later on. As my first real work with c++ I am having a issue. Basicly I am creating a daemon that will listen for clients natually since I am detacting the process from the enviroment you can see how I may want to log the output of this little daemon. So I devised this logger:

**core/log.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>

//define log levels
#define LOG_INFO  0
#define LOG_WARN  1
#define LOG_ERROR 2
#define LOG_CRIT  3
#define LOG_DEBUG 4

//Define functions
const std::string getDateTime();
void log(int, std::string);

//log file stream
std::ofstream logf;


const std::string getDateTime() {
 time_t    now = time(0);
 struct    tm tstruct;
 char      buf[80];
 tstruct = *localtime(&now);
 strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%Y.%m.%d_%H.%M.%S", &tstruct);
 return buf;
}

void log(int type, std::string message) {
 if (!logf.is_open()) {
  //attempt to open log file
  logf.open(("/var/log/dosocket/" + getDateTime() + ".log").c_str(), std::ios_base::app);
  if (!logf.is_open()) {
   //Failed to open
   std::cout << "FATEL: Failed to open log file!\n";
   exit(1);
  }
  //log type
  if(type == LOG_WARN) {
   logf << getDateTime() << " [WARNING]: " << message << "\n";
  }else if(type == LOG_INFO) {
   logf << getDateTime() << " [INFO]: " << message << "\n";
  }else if(type == LOG_DEBUG) {
   logf << getDateTime() << " [DEBUG]: " << message << "\n";
  }else if(type == LOG_ERROR) {
   logf << getDateTime() << " [ERROR]: " << message << "\n";
  }else if(type == LOG_CRIT) {
   logf << getDateTime() << " [CRITICAL]: " << message << "\n";
  }else{
   logf << getDateTime() << " [UNKNOWN]: " << message << "\n";
  }
 }
}
```

I have the logf variable at the top to keep it global. My thinking is that this would be better than opening the file stream>>appending message>>closing stream everything the log function is called. It will log once but then it never seems to do so again. I don't believe its a problem with the "global" variable I am keeping but I could be mistaken.

**socket.cpp (modified)**

```
 pid_t pid, sid;

 log(LOG_INFO, "Entering daemon"); //<-- line is logged
 //fork 1
 pid  = fork(); // Only doing one fork as well
 if (pid < 0) {
  log(LOG_CRIT, "fork() failed");
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
 }
 if (pid > 0) {
  log(LOG_INFO, "fork() complete, parent exited"); <-- is logged if entering daemon is commented out
  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
 }


 //umask & setsid
 if ((sid = setsid()) < 0) {
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
 }
 umask(0);

 //chdir
 if ((chdir("/")) < 0) {
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
 }

 close(STDIN_FILENO);
 close(STDOUT_FILENO);
 close(STDERR_FILENO);

 FILE* stdlog = fopen("/var/log/dosocket/std.log", "a+");

 dup2(fileno(stdlog), STDOUT_FILENO);
 dup2(fileno(stdlog), STDERR_FILENO);
 //testing bit to try and log std file descriptors.

//main process
 int sockfd, newsockfd, portno;
 socklen_t clilen;
 char buffer[256];
 struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
 int n;
 pid_t clipid;

 //create the socket
 log(LOG_INFO, "calling socket()"); <-- not logged
 sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
```

I'm sure you are able to see my confusion here. Any help/ideas are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: In`getDateTime()` your return local variable `buf` which is not correct. You should allocate new memory for that buffer. Also, use gdb (or other debugger) to see where do you get segfault.

Comment: Thanks that seems to of done it. I'll take a look into gdb

Comment: The global variable definition is of a class.  It destroys itself when it goes out of scope.  suggest moving to inside log function and making static.  Then it will be unchanged from one call to log() to the next call to log()

Comment: Okay, thanks for the suggestion I am doing that now.

Comment: @user3629249 would moving static std::ofstream logf; to the log() function do what you are suggesting?

Comment: @Rohan want to make sure; Would a bzero() do the job?

Comment: @HcgRandon, No, the memory may get overwritten by stack frame of other function making `bzero()` redundant.

Comment: @Rohan sorry for my lack of knowledge in this field. But I see your point. How could I free the memory and avoid redundancy?

Comment: @HcgRandon, I don't understand what are you asking.

Comment: @Rohan You said that bzero isn't sufficient for what I need yes? I was asking for a possible solution then..

Comment: @HcgRandon, as I said in ans, solution would be to allocate memory, return and later free it in `log()`. Or pass buf as param to `getDateTime()` to fill the string.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54896/discussion-between-hcgrandon-and-rohan).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `getDateTime()` your return local variable `buf` which is not correct. As local variable it will be on the stack, so contents may not be valid once the function returns.
You should allocate new memory for that buffer.

Also, use gdb (or other debugger) to see where do you get segfault.